# How to check is an input that is meant to be an integer is empty(in python)?

Tags: python, validation, input

```
def aboveIntegerInput(output_message="Enter your number: ", error_1="Please enter a number above {}!", error_2="Integers only!(Please do not leave this blank)", above=0):
  while True:
    try:
      user_input = int(input(output_message))
      if user_input >= above:
        return int(user_input)
        break
      else:
        print(error_1.format(above))
    except ValueError:
      print(error_2)
```

As you can see here the code is supposed to check if an input is an integer and it is above a certain value which by default is 0, but could be changed.

When the user inputs random letters and symbols it see that there is a value error and returns "Integers only!(Please do not leave this blank)".

I want to be able to check if the user inputs nothing, and in that case only it should output "This is blank/empty", the current way of dealing with this is to not check at all and just say "Integers only!(Please do not leave this blank)", in case there us a value error. I want to be able to be more specific and not just spit all the reasons at once. Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this :

```py
def aboveIntegerInput(output_message="Enter your number: ", error_1="Please enter a number above {}!", error_2="Integers only!", above=0, error_3="Please do not leave this blank"):
  while True:
    user_input = input(output_message)
    try:
        user_input = int(user_input)
        if user_input >= above:
            return user_input
            break
        else:
            print(error_1.format(above))
    except ValueError:
        if(not user_input):
            print(error_3)
        else:
            print(error_2)
```

I moved the input outside the try/except block to be able to use it in the except ! This worked fine for me, I hope this is what you needed.

Comment: Glad I could help, you're welcome ! By the way, I noticed that on the return statement, you convert user_input to an int a second time, which is not needed, since if the interpreter reaches the return, user_input will have to be an int already. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just break the input and the conversion to int into two steps, like this:

```
def aboveIntegerInput(output_message="Enter your number: ", error_1="Please enter a number above {}!", error_2="Integers only!(Please do not leave this blank)", above=0):
  while True:
    try:
      user_input = input(output_message)
      if not user_input:
         print("Please do not leave this blank")
         continue
      user_input = int(user_input)
      if user_input >= above:
        return int(user_input)
        break
      else:
        print(error_1.format(above))
    except ValueError:
      print(error_2)
```

Comment: The problem I found here is that if you do leave it blank, it will break out of the loop (line 7) so the function won't be able to complete its job. But thank you for your input.

Comment: You are right, I've edited the code: by using continue instead of break, you won't break out of the loop.